# Green "accepted" color has changed recently on some sites; was this intended?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I recently noticed some differences on the green shades (accepted answers, etc.) on The Workplace's Main and Meta sites, and raised a Meta question [there](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5024/green-colors-on-profile-have-changed).

However, further analyzing the situation I noticed that **the shades of green are different across some sites**. For example here on MSE we can see:

[image]

and on Stackoverflow we can see:

[image]

**Is there a reason for the differences of shades across these sites?** I know this is perhaps a minor detail (harmless I hope) but I couldn't help from noticing it.

**Edit:** If it helps, some tools I use indicate that the color on the first picture is `(141,178,98)` but on the second picture (the "previous" color) it is `(50,197,112)`.

Comment: Each SE site has it's own css styling.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that's worthy of an answer, with some more details if possible. :)

Comment: This is a recent change; neither Meta.SE nor Workplace main used to look like that.  I suspect there's a CSS bug somewhere.

Comment: @MonicaCellio that's what I thought. If you see TWP main site, you can even see that on the rep section the border line color is one and the text color (+10 or whatever) is another...

Comment: Amen!  There has been a recent change from a bright and happy green, to an olive green, (rather, pukey green).

Comment: @amWhy indeed, have you noticed it on other sites?

Comment: @DarkCygnus I see that Academia is using the pukey green for accepts, too.

Comment: Also Math.SE has changed to a pukey green.

Comment: Resist the urge to call this incident... 50 Shades of Green.

Comment: Ok.  I've spotted the (obvious) commonality here.  The pukey green is now used on all sites that have a customised theme.

Comment: Seems that Snow indeed spotted the diference

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fixed now. Good catch, thanks.

For the curious, here's what happened: The problem, to the surprise of absolutely no one, was [caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Yesterday we rolled out the CSS split that we've been [testing on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361881/115866) to the whole network.

The CSS files for all the sites are generated by [Less](http://lesscss.org/). But since a huge number of sites (those that do not have their own theme, but use the beta theme) have identical CSS, we have a caching layer in our build process so that we don't have to re-compile the CSS for every single beta site even though they're all the same.

This caching layer had an assumption in it that caused the caching to also apply to the secondary CSS files for sites that have their own theme. These secondary files are very similar across all sites, but they're not identical – in particular, as observed here, a couple of color values are different depending on the site.

Because of the overzealous caching, all sites that have a custom theme got the same secondary CSS file as the very first themed site whose Less file was compiled – and that site is [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) (because the compilation happens in alphabetical order).

Comment: Surely the first site in alphabetical order is 3D Printing, no? Which is why we see the 3DP icon take over everything from time to time?

Comment: @ArtOfCode Yes, 3D printing is the first *site* that's compiled, but it's a beta site. Academia is the first *themed* site.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I accidentally skipped reading a

Comment: Glad this was worked out, and thanks for your reply. Will check the changes when I get to PC and accept this answer after that.

Comment: Confirmed as working on the Workplace.  Greens are no longer puke coloured.

Comment: Thanks, @balpha!  MSE green back to happy green, no longer pukey green!

Answer (score 9):

Not only are Workplace main and meta different from each other, but this is a recent change on both Workplace and Meta.SE.  Here's a [snapshot from the Wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160414025900/http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/325/monica-cellio?tab=topactivity):

[image: main site with correct green]

I suspect there's a bug somewhere in the layers of CSS.  Maybe something that should have cascaded didn't, or vice-versa.